# Google web fonts not rendering when hosted

Tags: html, css

For my school project we have to make a small test site. When I run my site locally, my Google web fonts render perfectly.

But I am now hosting with Google drive and it will not render the Google fonts but choose the next one on the list. Here is my HTML and CSS, it may be an order issue or something.

[html](http://pastebin.com/3e5i3n7L)

[css](http://pastebin.com/0SbGXfPC)

Comment: Does taking them out of your HTML and adding: `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu); 
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300); `
 to the top of your CSS work?

Comment: I just noticed that the reason for them not rendering is because both firefox, chrome and IE block it, apparently it is insecure. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete guess, but does your link to the Google font look like this?

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css.......
```

If so, try changing it to:

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css........
```

This will allow the browser to use HTTPS if the main page itself is doing so, which I'm fairly sure it is if you're "hosting with Google drive".

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a pretty darn good stab in the dark because it works perfectly

Comment: I shall add one to me "successful blind snipes" counter ;)